# Is this the right sentence?

Tags: american-english

After I had sent an e-mail to co-worker with a few files attached, I realized that some files were corrupted. So I am willing to send a mail again with the fixed files.
Can I use a sentence like this?

Sorry, it seems has been corrupted, I wiling to send again with normal file.

Comment: Simply send the email with the proper files attached, perhaps with a message similar to: *"Sorry, the files I had previously sent you were (probably) corrupted. Here are the good ones."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a subject word in the first half of your sentence, and the wording is a little off.

It looks as though you're planning to simply send your coworker a new email with the undamaged files, is that correct? If so a better way of saying this would be:

"Sorry, it seems as though the files I sent were corrupted. I will send you the undamaged files"

If you're asking whether or not the coworker wants you to send them the files again, I would say:

"Sorry, it seems as though the files I sent were corrupted. Did you need me to resend the files to you?"

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks PDL, but I have some curiosity your question about "is that correct?" Firstly, Which point was exactly making you as ambiguous in my total sentence?

Comment: Sure, so when you say "I willing to send again with normal file" you're indicating that you're _willing_ to send the files again if they ask, but you haven't already sent it, or are specifically going to send it unless they ask. It's ambiguous. In business communication it's best to be as specific as possible, that way there is no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use "Sorry, it seems the files I sent are corrupted, Can I send the mail again with the fixed files ?".